# Trouble iterating lines from a text file in Python for reuse

Tags: python-2.7, split

I am having trouble iterating a process in Python 2.7.
I have simplified it as much as possible to debug the first steps, and want to build on this.
If I specify the data

```
data = ("-4.916409,36.629535,3.721236,255,232,242")
```

And then get it to split

```
X,Y,Z,R,G,B = data.split(",")
```

I can recombine some of the elements to create new files and/or folders with the name of those elements:

```
RGB = (R + "+" + G + "+" + B)
os.makedirs(inputFolder + os.sep + RGB)
fo = open("Z:\\temp\\output" + os.sep + RGB + os.sep + RGB + ".txt", "w")
fo.write(X + "," + Y + "," + Z + "\n")
```

But when I try to do that from a longer text file, I can no longer combine the elements into this "RGB" as a file and/or folder name (only "R" or "G" or "B"), and only get a return for the first line.

```
inputFolder = ("Z:\\temp\\output")
coordinates = open("Z:\\temp\\accident2.txt", "r")
for line in coordinates:
   X,Y,Z,R,G,B = line.split(",")
   RGB = (R + "+" + G + "+" + B)
   os.makedirs(inputFolder + os.sep + R)
   fo = open("Z:\\temp\\output" + os.sep + R + os.sep + R + ".txt", "w")
   fo.write(X + "," + Y + "," + Z + "\n")
```

But it works if I switch from the whole numbers to the decimals:

```
RGB = (X + "," + Y + "," + Z)
```

Then I can write:

```
fo = open("Z:\\temp\\output" + os.sep + RGB + os.sep + RGB + ".txt", "w")
```

Which is not quite right, but closer to what I want.
Why are numbers with decimals easier to "read" than those without?
How do I fix it so the whole numbers are treated like those with decimals?

Answer (score 0):

well your coordinates is a file object, you need to read from this object. You can actually read line-by-line using readlines, function of file object. Check documentation

```
inputFolder = ("Z:\\temp\\output")
with open("Z:\\temp\\accident2.txt", "r") as coordinates:
   for linenumber,line in enumerate( coordinates.readlines() ):
      X,Y,Z,R,G,B = line[:-1].split(",")
      RGB = (R + "+" + G + "+" + B)
      try:
         os.makedirs(inputFolder + os.sep + R)
         fo = open("Z:\\temp\\output" + os.sep + R + os.sep + R + ".txt", "w")
         fo.write(X + "," + Y + "," + Z + "\n")
      except:
         print "problem in line %d"%linenumber
```

Comment: Could you please posted an error message. Oversize i'm just guessing what may be your problem. Also if you read lines, add something to debug, which line create a problem. I've updated my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: please update question and problem description. Be precise in description as possible.

Comment: float point numbers must have a period, which is a separator between filename and extension in Fat file system. Is this the answer? ;)

Comment: print out your filename X + "," + Y + "," + Z and try to create it manually. Does it works?

Comment: It's because the Z was the last value in the line; it works if I just use the X and Y values..
So I need to use `.rstrip("\r\n")` to get rid of the invisible line returns.
Not working as `line = coordinates.readline().rstrip("\r\n")` or as `X,Y,Z,R,G,B = line.split(",").rstrip("\r\n")` or as a separate line: `string.rstrip("\r\n")` or `str.rstrip("\r\n")`

Comment: Solution:
`X,Y,Z,R,G,B = line.split(",")
B = B.rstrip("\r\n")`
Finally!!!

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right! I forgot add usul [:-1] to line which was read. Sorry! I've update my answer.